# Grabbing user id of current logged user and add it as foreign key value in a different table returns null - MySQL - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreign-keys

I'm trying to insert data based on current logged in user. I'm grabbing the user email address from the session data, then I query users table for the user_id that matches the unique email address but upon inserting it throws Error Number: 1452.

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ecamara`.`institution_contact_info`, CONSTRAINT `institution_contact_info_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`institution_users_id`) REFERENCES `institution_users` (`institution_users_id`))

I'm left thinking that when I retrieve the email address from the session data, it does
not return any values.

Here is what I've tried;

login.php controller

```
public function login_validate()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Institution Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|callback_validate_credentials');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
    //$query = $this->form_validation->run();

    if($this->form_validation->run()) //if user credentials validate
    {
        $data = array(
            'email_address' => $this->input->post('email_address'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
            );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data); 
        redirect('login/members_area');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->index();
    }       
}
```

This is the callback function

```
public function validate_credentials()
{
    $this->load->model('institution_users_model'); 

    if($this->institution_users_model->validate())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_credentials', 'Incorrect Email/Password');
        return false;
    }
}
```

vetting.php controller

```
public function create_contact()
{
    $this->load->model('institution_users_model');
    $create_institution_contact = $this->institution_users_model->create_institution_contact();
    if($create_institution_contact)
    {
        redirect('vetting/success_message');
    }
    else{
        redirect('vetting/institution_contact_info');
    }
}
```

institution_users_model.php

```
public function validate()
{
    $this->db->where('email_address', $this->input->post('email_address'));
    $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $query = $this->db->get('institution_users');

    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }   
}

public function create_member()
{
    $user_data = array(
        'institution_name' => $this->input->post('institution_name'),
        'email_address' => $this->input->post('email_address'),
        'password' => md5($this->input->post('password'))
    );
    $insert = $this->db->insert('institution_users', $user_data);

    if($insert)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}

public function create_institution_contact()
{
    $email_address = $this->session->userdata('email_address');
    $this->db->select('institution_users.institution_users_id');
    $this->db->where('institution_users.email_address', $email_address);
    $institution_users = $this->db->get('institution_users');
    $result = $institution_users->result();
    $institution_users_id = $result[0]->institution_users_id;

    $contact_data = array(
        'institution_users_id' => '$institution_users_id',
        'institution_registration_no' => $this->input->post('institution_registration_no'),
        'institution_address' => $this->input->post('institution_address'),
        'institution_telephone_no' => $this->input->post('institution_telephone_no'),
        'website' => $this->input->post('website')
    );

    $insert_contact = $this->db->insert('institution_contact_info', $contact_data);
    if($insert_contact)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to check whether the session data $email_address had a value, then perform the query and finally iterate over the elements of the array result $institution_users being returned to access the value for the variable $institution_users_id.

Here is the modified function create_institution_contact();

```
public function create_institution_contact()
{       
    $email_address = $this->session->userdata('email_address');
    if($email_address){
        $this->db->where('institution_users.email_address', $email_address);
        $institution_users = $this->db->get(institution_users); 
        foreach($institution_users->result() as $row)
        {
            $institution_users_id = $row->institution_users_id;
        }
    }               

    $contact_data = array(
        'institution_users_id' => $institution_users_id,
        'institution_registration_no' => $this->input->post('institution_registration_no'),
        'institution_address' => $this->input->post('institution_address'),
        'institution_telephone_no' => $this->input->post('institution_telephone_no'),
        'website' => $this->input->post('website')
    );

    $insert_contact = $this->db->insert('institution_contact_info', $contact_data);
    if($insert_contact)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's got little to do with the app code layer.  The database foreign key error is your clue to check the DB schema and see what dependencies are needed prior to adding an institution.

I'm guessing you'll need to define that "institution" record prior to inserting a user

Figure it out by running

> SHOW CREATE TABLE institution_users\G

using mysql client.  Check the ecamara table too